# sqlite query with IN parameter in different condition

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table in sqlite named Devices which has following columns

```
Id, DeviceId, FavBrands, FavCategories
```

the sample data in it is

```
 1        50ea9017cb5ad            1,2,8,9           4,6,8
 2        50ead1683dcc0            3,7,9             4,5,9
 3        50ee73b56c4ea            1,2,7             6,7,8
```

I want to query this table to return deviceid which has FavBrands 7 in them
relationg to table above it should give row number 2 and 3.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may use this:

```
SELECT * FROM Devices
WHERE instr(','||FavBrands||',' , ',7,')>0;
```

(An obligatory remark about please normalizing your database, with a link to
[Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)).

If you heed another advice and use `LIKE`, ensure you use `'%,7,%'` and add commas as we do here, to avoid false positives (e.g. with `77` in the list).

Comment: but what if there is no comma after 7 just like in row 3.... it s ',7' so will it match

Comment: instr is not supported in sqlite

Comment: old version, maybe? http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html (as of "7" at the end, that's why I *both* append *and* prepend comma to FavBrands)